# How we can implement attribute prediction and image search model as one?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

We want to implement attribute prediction and image search model in single application.

Step1. Upload of image ,will give attribute details.
example ,If we upload dog image, then attribute details will display like color, breed.

step2. On click of any attribute will show similar matching result.

example on click of attribute  like breed it will display matching breed  dog images from image data.

Please suggest ,how we can achieve that

Answer (score 1):

With step 1, I recommend you should use a multi-label images classification. It will help you get attribute of input image like what object in in the image, what color is it,...
With step 2, you can query the attribute in your database or you can use a recommendation system for more advance.